# Wireless Controller 5520 Creating a dynamic interface

Tags: cisco, wireless, interface, wan, access-point

I'm hoping to determine the least intrusive way to configuring my WLC.

I am working through the GUI interface and have created a new dynamic interface
[Controller-> Interfaces]

When I went to configure the interface, I was stopped with a warning message.
"Changes to an interface will disable WLAN while the radios reset"

This is a concern because I'm in an environment where I can't just reset the Wifi.

What I am hoping to find out - this interface isn't connected to any WLAN, so will me making changes to it really reset all of the other WLANS?

I could not find any information in the documentation

*"Step 6

Click Save Configuration to save your changes.
Step 7

Repeat this procedure for each dynamic interface that you want to create or edit. "*

Thank you,

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer - I googled "Note: Changing the Interface parameters causes the WLANs to be temporarily disabled and thus may result in loss of connectivity for some clients."

it lead me to another post stating that only SSID's with a direct link to the interface would be reset. Because this is a brand new interface - no resets would be done.

I will experience a reset to the single WLAN when I change the interface to a new interface group(this is exected) - other ssids should be unaffected